# Get expect to take a variable with whitespaces in it

Tags: linux, shell

In my expect script I have two variables I would like to add.  Both of them will be variables into the script.

```
 hello="My Life" 
 world="is wonderful" 
 ./script.sh $hello $world
```

in script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
match_max 100000000

set first_var [lindex $argv 0]
set second_var [lindex $argv 1]
```

Currently,

```
first_var="My"
second_var="Life"
```

The code below works as expected when don't pass in them in as variables.

```
./script.sh 'My Life' 'is wonderful'
```

I need to know how to have that script take in the variables and still ignore white space within them.

Comment: use `./script.sh "$hello" "$world"`

Comment: Is [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) the best dupe we have for this? It's a bit indirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the variables within quotes as well;

./script.sh "$hello" "$world"

The way Bash expansion works, these variables will be expanded out before the script is run.  It will be the same as if the command were run as

./script "My life" "is wonderful"

The quotes around parameters indicate to the shell not to split via the field separator.